# Effects of Shaders on Mob Spawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, (most) mobs spawn based off of light levels.

Shaders alter the lighting of the game. Some shaders will make dark corners appear even darker than in the ordinary game. Some shaders might make the game brighter or darker on average.

Does the presence of a shader mean it might be more easy for mobs to spawn? Does the game read in the shader's light levels, or is it something more internal?

Thanks!

Comment: TLDR I don't think so because shaders only change the look of the game, not actual light levels or anything like that. However, if you have a shader you can check. In Minecraft, open F3 and check the light level in one of those spots which might change brightness with a shader installed. Then, enable the shader and check the same spot in the same way, making sure the time of day (ingame) is the same and making sure that all light sources are in the same position. If the light levels are the same, shaders have no effect. If they are different, shaders do affect spawning.

Comment: What mod and what shader are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

The most common shader mods are only client-side, the server doesn't care about that. Since the server handles mob spawning, shaders don't affect it.

Light levels and actual visible light are also different in Vanilla, for example there is "smooth lighting", which can make blocks considerably brighter or darker in certain situations than is normal for their light level, as well as a brightness setting, night vision, blindness, the different amounts of underwater vision, grass and leaves have different colours and brightness in different biomes and so on. These all don't matter for the server.
What matters for the server is the light level, which you can see in the debug screen. Most mob spawning happens at light level 7 or lower, so for example 7 blocks away from the nearest torch.